# dataframe from list of `(row, column, value)`?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of tuples in `(row, column, value)` format (coming from sql query). Eg

```
data = [
    (date_1, brand_x, 5),
    (date_1, brand_y, 8),
    (date_2, brand_x, 12)
]
```

and I want to convert them to a dataframe

```
index  | brand_x | brand_y
--------------------------
date_1 |   5     |    8
date_2 |  12     |   NaN
```

I've been trying with `Dataframe.from_records/from_dict` and different `orient` values, but to no avail. What is the correct way to do it?

PS: If there's a way to do it by converting the tuples to dicts first, it's just as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
data = [
    ('date_1', 'brand_x', 5),
    ('date_1', 'brand_y', 8),
    ('date_2', 'brand_x', 12)
]    

pd.DataFrame(data).pivot_table(index=0,columns=1)
```

Comment: Also, `pd.DataFrame(data)pivot(index=0,columns=1,values=2).reset_index()`

Comment: `pivot` is better since you are not aggregating data via a function.